# Проверка окончания закрузки файла selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Имеется минимальный скрипт который скачивает файл по нажатию, но скрипт отрабатывает неккоректно так как закрывается по клику и появляется недоконца загруженный файл (example.pic.crdownload). Я так понимаю что нужно как то реализовать механизм проверки загруженности файла. Можно конечно просто заставить уснуть код на секунду, но как по мне это костыль. Помогите пожалуйста реализовать данный механизм.

Пример кода ниже:

```
from selenium import webdriver


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

site = 'somesite'
driver.get(site)
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("downloadPic")
element.click()
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант вы можете получить ссылку для загрузки, закрыть браузер, и скачать файл через **requests**

```
import requests

with open('home.jpg', "wb") as file:
    response = requests.get('https://ramziv.com/static/assets/img/home-bg.jpg')
    file.write(response.content)
```

Comment: Могло бы стать решением, но к сожалению в данном случае файл генерируется js'кой и никакой ссылки к файлу нет :(